# mysql master and slave has different schema alter table add column

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.6

I have added column in large table it was having some unique index which was causing issue,So i drop index and add column and after adding column i have added unique index.
But all of my slave is broke they don't have master schema,
I am not sure how to solve this problem

`ALTER TABLE User ADD COLUMN foo_bar VARCHAR(255);`
Table also consist of email which has unique index

MySql Version :  5.6.30,
Master Create Table

```
CREATE TABLE `gobe_User` (
  `uuid` bigint(32) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
   `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `encrypted_password` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
   UNIQUE KEY `uuid` (`uuid`) USING BTREE,
    UNIQUE KEY `emai_2` (`email`),
     KEY `email` (`email`),
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=ucs2 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

Slave Create Table

```
    CREATE TABLE `gobe_User` (
      `uuid` bigint(32) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
       `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
      `email` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,

       UNIQUE KEY `uuid` (`uuid`) USING BTREE,
        UNIQUE KEY `emai_2` (`email`),
         KEY `email` (`email`),
         ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=ucs2 ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

Comment: Provide us the exact statements performed, in order.  Also, provide the version(s) of the Master and Slave(s).

Comment: @RickJames updated description

Comment: `foo_bar` is not `email`, correct?  Where is the `ADD UNIQUE`?

Comment: foo_bar is new column and email is already unique indexed

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE ...` for the Master and one of the Slaves.

Comment: @RickJames updated description

Comment: You win the boobie prize -- No one uses `CHARSET=ucs2`.  Why are you using it?

Comment: @RickJames it's very old db around 2011 so i am not sure why they used it

Comment: I don't _think_ usc2 is at fault.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I see no reason why the `ALTER` would not propagate to the Slave(s) and work there.  Suggest you apply the `ALTER` to each Slave.  You might need a `SLAVE START` to get them running after that.  Then proceed with the `ADD UNIQUE`, etc.

PS, A `UNIQUE KEY` is a "key", so you have a redundant index on `email`.

Comment: Slave is already started should i stop slave and then run alter command then start slave,

Comment: @Amar - That depends on what commands were "skipped" to get the slave started.

Comment: Is it possible If disk space is not sufficient at slave which break this issue?

Comment: Is the disk space near zero now?